# Spring @Asnyc method call and threadsafety for arguments passed to async methods

Tags: spring, asynchronous, thread-safety

I wanted to ask how Spring @Async annotated methods do handle with objects passed as a arguments.
The async method execution will create another thread. In this case the caller and the new thread have both a reference to the objects passed in as arguments. That means both threads are able to mutate the same objects. This may lead to false results. I wanted to ask how Spring is handling this. Maybe the objects passed in as arguments are somehow copied/cloned?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

Spring is not even try to handle it. It is your responsibility as a developer to implement the method so it works correctly in concurrent environment. [Accessing shared data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing#Coordinating_access_to_resources) is a general problem (or I would say implication) of [concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing) which has its [solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control).

Comment: Thanks. That means I should only read-access the object passed in as argument to a async method but never actually mutate it?

Comment: No necessarily. Even read-only access can be dangerous or work incorrectly, for example you may see inconsistent data if you execute two consecutive reads. It is a very broad topic to answer it shortly. I recommend to read this great book http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601 to understand concurrency.

Comment: Furthermore you can mutate object, just need to do it thread-safely.