# Sending bulk mails periodically

Tags: java, spring-boot, architecture, restful-architecture

I have a requirement where i have to send 100 mails/minute/user and it is time specific.(i.e All the mails i.e 100*1000 = 10000 mails/min should go on same time)

Currently there are almost 1000 users.

As well as for each email i am saving it first then sending it.

What things i need to implement for better performance and achieve goal optimally.

[Note: All the emails are sent via different accounts, so limit wont increase]

Any suggestion will be very helpful.

I am currently using Spring Boot for the project.

Comment: You'll need to distribute the process. Sending 10k emails a minute from a single IP is just going to get you blocked.

Comment: It will be hard to achieve sending 10000 mails simultaniously. Does it have a hard or soft deadline? I have previously answered a similar question about threads in Spring. Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141731/spring-threads-in-web-app/43141843#43141843

Comment: @Michael Any idea how do i distribute process, If incase you have done so far.

Comment: @kkflf Its not hard deadline.

Comment: @utsavanand The easiest way is to use a service [like Mailchimp](https://developer.mailchimp.com/) with a rich API. It'll cost you a little bit, though.

Comment: @Michael We are not allowed to use any third party service.

Comment: You could use `@Scheduled` in combination with `@Async`. This would enable you do process a bulk of emails per X seconds

Comment: @utsavanand Then you're looking at rolling out a custom load balancer spreading the emails across >10 private servers. It will be more expensive and take longer.

Comment: @utsavanand I have added a solution that will fit a soft deadline. You can mail it out in batches.

Comment: @kkflf He said all the emails should go at the same time.

Comment: That is true, but I just asked him if it was a hard or soft deadline? So I posted a solution that he can tweak to achieve a acceptable number of emails with the processing power that is avaliable for him.

Comment: Thanks @kkflf  For your suggestion..

Comment: @Michael thanks for your reply..will surely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Service for this, if project run on windows server.

Comment: Project In on Linux

Comment: Ok, i dont know linux, but you need external an app for this operation. You can try paid email send services mailchimp or etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Remember to set @EnableScheduling
//in the class containing your main method
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}

@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    List<Email> listOfEmails;

    int nextBatch = 50;
    int curBatch = 0;

    //This method will run every 15 second.
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 15000)
    public void yourMethodName() {
        //This will process all of your objects all at once using treads
        for(int i = curBatch; i < maxBatchSize(); i++){
            listOfEmails.get(i).process();
        }
        nextBatch+=50;
        curBatch+=50;
    }

    private int maxBatchSize(){
        if(nextBatch < listOfEmails.size()){
            return nextBatch;
        } else {
            return listOfEmails.size();
        }
    }
}



public class YourObject {

    Integer someTest = 0;

    @Async
    public void process(Email e) {
        e.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: The above is only a codesnippet. But this would enable you to send out the email in batches.

Comment: This is a bad suggestion because spring boot `@Async` does not guarantee the preservation of parameters in calls. This may cause some mails not being sent. You can find detailed information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238796/spring-asnyc-method-call-and-threadsafety-for-arguments-passed-to-async-methods).

Comment: True @Fatih , people just give the answer without trying at their end first or without knowing the consequences of their code!

Comment: This is just a code snippet and not a final solution. You always have to be careful about thread-safety - It is a common issue with all software systems. My answer assumed that the Email object is/was immutable. There are several things that have to be changed to make this code snippet a production-ready solution. This is not about `@Async` not "preserving" parameters, this is a common thread-safety issue. Spring is not magic - you need to be aware of thread-safety.